# manipulate css on multiple spans with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to manipulate spans based on what is contained in them. on my company's ecommerce site there are two spans that contain the price of an item and the sale price of an item. not all items have sale prices. problem is the original price span is shown with the text-decoration set to line-though regardless of whether or not there is a sale price. since i can't interact with the database that contains product info (platform won't allow it) i have to use javascript to correct this. I need to hide the span that contains the sale price if no sale price is present and remove the text-decoration on the other span that contains the original price. currently the code (below) i have will hide the sale span, but i can only get it to remove the text-decoration on all or none of the list price spans. Any ideas?

```
$(function(){
    $(".container > .special").each(function(){
        var specialContents = $(this).text();
        var isEmpty = specialContents.substr(0, 7);

        if(isEmpty != "Sale: $"){
            $(this).hide();
        }

    });
});
```

each set of spans is wrapped in a div with class container and the spans have the classes 'list' for the original or list price and 'special' for the sale price, Also, the first 6 characters of every special span will be "Sale: " regardless of if it has a price or not.
Thanks in advance

Comment: We need to see some sample HTML; it's very hard to determine what you're getting at here. Also, you cannot give multiple elements the same `id`; you should probably be using `class` instead, or just jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Comment: can you show us a sample of the html?

Comment: <div class="container"><span class="list">List Price: $xx.xx</span><span class="special">Sale: $xx.xx</span></div>

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `$(this)` refers to all the `.special` elements. When doing an [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you should have two paramaters - one for the index and one for the current item. This will allow you to reference the single item.

```
$(".container > .special").each(function(i,item){
        var $item = item,
            specialContents = $item.text(),
            isEmpty = specialContents.substr(0, 7);

        if(isEmpty != "Sale: $"){
            $item.hide().attr('id', 'hidden');
        }

    });
```

Also, you're probably setting `id` for multiple elements to be `hidden` which isn't a good idea (ID should always be unique). You can also chain the `hide()` and `attr()` methods together to save a selector. I also just set up `$item` to save another jQuery selector.

If you're looking to change the CSS, then instead of `$item.hide()` you can use the [css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to do something like:

```
$item.css('text-decoration','none');
```

If, for example, you wanted to change the sibling span with the `list` class, you can do this:

```
$item.siblings('.list').css('text-decoration','none');
```

Comment: +1 for the point that ID is supposed to be unique. If you need to set multiple items to have a single reference, use a class (you can have multiple classes on a single element).

Comment: really i was trying to find a way to change the css on the .list span. this works fine to hide the .special if no price is listed, i just cant change the text-decoration on the .list spans for only the instances where the .special span is hidden

Comment: u can use .addClass('hidden') which will just add another class to the element instead of changing its .attr('id', 'hidden')

Comment: @heymrcarter: Not sure if I'm understanding correctly. If you want to iterate through the `.special` spans in order to update the `.list` sibling span, then you can use the `siblings` method. I've updated my answer to explain. To modify some CSS of the span, use `.css` or `.addClass` if you have a CSS class already.

Comment: @Jonathon: i want to remove the text-decoration on the .list span if the .special span is hidden. otherwise keep the text-decoration as line-through

Comment: inside the ` if(isEmpty != "Sale: $"){` block,
add the folowing:
`$item.prev().css('text-decoration','none');`

Comment: this throws the error "Object #<an HTMLElement> has no method 'text'" where specialContents = $item.text(), is called

Comment: if i remove the parameters in the .each() function everything works fine. adding $item.siblings('.list').css('text-decoration','none'); inside the if statement does the trick

Comment: What you write is not correct , `this` refers to the current element: *More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.* http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @Felix Ah - my bad. Thanks for pointing it out. I don't know why I was dead set on that being the case. Something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Given this HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="list">List Price: $xx.xx</span>
    <span class="special">Sale: $xx.xx</span></div>
<div class="container">
    <span class="list">List Price: $xx.xx</span>
    <span class="special">Empty</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <span class="list">List Price: $xx.xx</span>
    <span class="special">Sale: $xx.xx</span>
</div>
```

[**your code should work**](http://jsfiddle.net/WYkWf/2/). Here with removal of the `line-through`:

```
$(".container > .special").each(function() {
    var specialContents = $(this).text();
    var isEmpty = specialContents.substr(0, 7);

    if (isEmpty != "Sale: $") {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev().css('text-decoration', 'none');
    }
});
```

Of course if your HTML is different from that, than it won't work.